# How to have elements under position fixed div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to use `position:fixed;` for top div so the animation happens then I want to show other content and elements under it .

[image]

Right now the hello divs are over the container which I want them to be under the blue container .

This is the [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-forked-d3bp4?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the `body` is the blue container, so you can't put anything outside of that, but you could style another element as the blue container. [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) can be used to control what appears above/below other positioned elements.